# Ingesting versioned S3 files into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to copy data from a versioning enabled S3 bucket to Snowflake. Is there a way to ingest a specific version (or all versions) of a given file directly into Snowflake? If not, what would be the best work around to ingest all versions and not only the latest one using Snowflake?

Comment: Hi, this sounds like you need to manage something external to Snowflake tbh